# Windows Phone 8.0 Dojo Tab Bar is Displaced! What to do?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, dojo, tabbar

I have created a new Windows Phone 8 app with `Cordova/PhoneGap`. 
                                                                                                       I create the visual objects with `dojo 1.9.3` so the most objects are displayed perfect for me.
Only the Tab Bar is displaced that the rigth bottom of the bar is not visible, it goes out of the screen!

```
<!--Tab Bar-->
<ul data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/TabBar" fixed="bottom" id="tabBar" baseclass="editBar">
<style type="text/css">
       .editBar {
        color: aqua;     
                }
</style>
<!-- fixed="bottom">
<!--style width is a workarround for a too big footer tabbar witch makes the app horizonatl scrollable  style="overflow-x: hidden;"-->
<li label="Login" id="tabBarButtonLogin" dojotype="dojox/mobile/TabBarButton" moveto="generalView1" icon1="css/login_60.png" icon2="css/login_60.png" selected="true"></li>
<li label="Knoten" id="tabBarButtonNodes" dojotype="dojox/mobile/TabBarButton" moveto="generalView2" icon1="css/nodes_60.png" icon2="css/nodes_60.png"></li>
<li label="Info" id="tabBarButtonInfo" dojotype="dojox/mobile/TabBarButton" moveto="generalView3" icon1="css/info_60.png" icon2="css/info_60.png"></li>
        </ul>
```

[image]

I don't know how to fix the problem...
If anyone has a answer I would be thankful!